# Block direct access to port which is using app

Tags: .htaccess

I am running an app on port 799. I would like to prevent people from accessing via direct access:

```
http://www.website.com:799/folder/1
```

However, I need that port to still listen and operate otherwise. For example, certain pages direct the user to

```
http://www.website.com:799/folder/1
```

after checking to see whether they are members. The link is never actually revealed as a url to the user. Is there anyway to specify via htaccess to block contents when the user has requested directly via url but otherwise let the contents show. (When they are requested via php).

Comment: How are you preventing the user from seeing the URL?

Comment: the url is embedded in an iframe. It doesn't show up in the url bar. The user can view the iframe source and skip all membership checks and enter.

Comment: You could check a HTTP referer, but it is not a reliable solutions.